# Excel doesn't recognize formulas when excel is exported and created from c#

Tags: c#, excel, xlsm

I'm downloading an excel .xlsm from my application web, the problem is that when I opened there is a formula "=MyFunction(E16)" that appears as "#NAME?" so I think the formula isn't recognized.

My file is protected so it can't be edited (only the valid cells).

When I unprotect the excel and press enter in the #NAME? cell it is fixed. But in a normal case the user couldn't do that.

What is happening? Somebody can help me?

Comment: sProbably a security issue relating to macros -- XSS or something.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-in-excel-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4 have you tried this>? Change to automatic formula calculation ?